# Do I need 35 hours of ground school for knowledge test for PPL?

Tags: usa, ppl, faa-knowledge-test, far-141

New US student here. I'm starting part 141 flight training soon for my private pilot license, but for now prepping for the knowledge test. I am going with self-study and had a question about endorsement for the written exam.

Is the endorsement I get from the [ASA Prepware tool](http://www.asa2fly.com/Prepware-Practice-Tests-P876C772.aspx) sufficient for taking the knowledge test?

> Complete two practice tests with scores of 80% or better, and request your test sign-off (endorsement) from ASA

I am confused because I've been under the impression that part 141 mandates 35 hours of ground school for taking the knowledge test (also 35 hours of flight time).

https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=2d180e467a3b85b2e34ce695dea3d322&mc=true&node=pt14.3.141&rgn=div5#sp14.3.141.f

> Appendix B to Part 141—Private Pilot Certification Course
>
> (a) Each approved course must include at least the following ground training on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed in paragraph (b) of this section, appropriate to the aircraft category and class rating:
>
> (1) 35 hours of training if the course is for an airplane, rotorcraft, or powered-lift category rating.

If not, I might just do Sporty's ground school ($200) and get my endorsement that way.

Thanks

Comment: Why 141, if I may ask?

Comment: I don't know much about part 141 but I suggest you check their syllabus and requirements before doing anything. A part 141 school can have "examining authority", which means that they test and approve their own students and you don't need to do the regular FAA knowledge and practical tests at all. Make sure you really understand how the school's program works before you spend any money on anything. They should be able to explain that to you easily.

Answer (score 1):

For 141 you need a graduation certificate to take the test. For part 61 you need an instructor endorsement. 141 is for complete courses start to end. 61 is for getting a piece here and a piece there mix and match style. in either case there is a minimum amount of ground training required before you can get your private certificate.

Any either case you don't need the knowledge test to start flying, you only need the knowledge test before your final FAA check ride.